# While conditional statement not working in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, do-while, jmeter-3.2

I am attempting to add a simple conditional statement for a while controller, however it fails to stop when the condition has been met.

```
     While controller
          Counter
          http request - status request identifies the current status of process (submitted, pre_processed and processed)
          xpath extraction - extracts the  response status which is saved to a variable
          Debug  - Debug confirms the variable is correct
```

The conditional statement is as follows:

```
       ${__javaScript("${getStatus}" == "PROCESSED" || ${counter} < 5),)}
```

I then modified to make it even easier:

```
        ${__javaScript("${getStatus}" == "PROCESSED")}
```

The log shows no error or syntax error, however it fails to stop when status is PROCESSED.

I have attempted the following alternatives and it does not work:

```
          ${__javaScript("vars.get("getStatus")" == "PROCESSED")}
          ${__javaScript("${getStatus}".indexOf("PROCESSED") == "PROCESSED")}
          ${__javaScript(" '${getStatus}' != 'SUBMITTED' " || " '{$getStatus}' !=  'PRE_PROCESSED' " ,)}
```

I think the issue is the syntax, but at a lost what is wrong with my statement.

Comment: Your are saying "The log shows no error or syntax error, however it fails to stop when status is PROCESSED." the while loop with the statement ${__javaScript("${getStatus}" == "PROCESSED")} wont stop unless status IS NOT PROCESSED. if you want it to stop when the status is PROCESSED then change your statement to ${__javaScript("${getStatus}" != "PROCESSED")}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [jexl3](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)  function instead of javascript for performance reasons and also the condition should return true so revert the equal aign:

```
   ${__jexl3("${getStatus}" != "PROCESSED")}
```